# Unable to run react jest test cases azure msal

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, msal.js, msal-react

I am working on react app, integrated msal library for azure authentications. I am trying to setup jest in project to run test cases. But i am getting error while running tests.

```
 export { MsalConsumer, MsalContext } from './MsalContext.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

   7 |   RedirectRequest,
   8 | } from '@azure/msal-browser'
>  9 | import {MsalProvider} from '@azure/msal-react'
     | ^
  10 |
  11 | // Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
  12 | export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
```

jest.config.ts

```
const esModules = ['@azure/msal-react', '@azure/msal-browser'].join('|');

export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    transform: { '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest' },
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage",
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@azure/msal-react)).*\\.ts$",
    ],

    testPathIgnorePatterns: [`<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!${esModules}`],
    coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "html"],

}
```